# wpf: getting exception while adding "CrystalReportsViewer" control from Toolbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, crystal-reports

I have installed "Crystal Report (Service Pack 20)" for visual studio 2015. Whenever i drag "CrystalReportsViewer" from toolbox to **WPF** window and run the program i get an exception error saying " **Additional information: The invocation of the constructor on type 'SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.ViewerCore' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.** "

The inner exception of the above exception is

> The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw
>   an exception.

again the inner exception of the above exception is

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"log4net,
>   Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304

i have installed 32 bit and then 64 bit for checking compatibility issues but this did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1st. the runtime have to be the same of the project, no the SO's version.
2nd. when you generate the project, exclude the .dll's (CrystalReports and CrystalDecisions)
3rd. You have to copy 'log4net.dll' to the next directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet.

**You have to search 'log4net.dll' in the web. I had a old link and it's not working anymore.